# Basinhopping Causes Error with Statsmodels MNLogit

Tags: python, optimization, statsmodels, mlogit

I tried running the code below to fit a multinomial Logit model using the basinhopping method, but it returns the following error:

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

x = np.random.randint(0, 100, 1000)
y = np.random.randint(0, 3, 1000)
model = sm.MNLogit(y, sm.add_constant(x))
results = model.fit(method='basinhopping')
print(results.summary())
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/wagnerpf134/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder_kernels/py3compat.py", line 356, in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File "/Users/wagnerpf134/Documents/untitled0.py", line 7, in <module>
    results = model.fit(method='basinhopping')

  File "/Users/wagnerpf134/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/discrete/discrete_model.py", line 654, in fit
    mnfit = base.LikelihoodModel.fit(self, start_params = start_params,

  File "/Users/wagnerpf134/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/base/model.py", line 563, in fit
    xopt, retvals, optim_settings = optimizer._fit(f, score, start_params,

  File "/Users/wagnerpf134/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/base/optimizer.py", line 241, in _fit
    xopt, retvals = func(objective, gradient, start_params, fargs, kwargs,

  File "/Users/wagnerpf134/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/base/optimizer.py", line 1040, in _fit_basinhopping
    retvals = optimize.basinhopping(f, start_params,

  File "/Users/wagnerpf134/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_basinhopping.py", line 728, in basinhopping
    callback(bh.storage.minres.x, bh.storage.minres.fun, True)

TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

The error does not appear when I specify other optimization methods, and it does not appear when I use basinhopping with Statsmodel's Logit model on binary dependent variables or OrderedModel(distr='logit') on ordered categorical dependent variables, so I'm not really sure what's going wrong. Any help in resolving this error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ok, I have edited my post to include the traceback.

Comment: That's a bug, and there is no workaround. MNLogit loglike is usually well behaved, and I guess nobody ever tried basinhopping with it. I opened https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/8665

Comment: The only workaround would be monkey-patching the MNLogit.fit method.

Comment: Ah, I see. So if I really wanted to monkey-patch it as you say, I could probably change the name of callback in MNLogit.fit to something else and you think that would resolve the issue?

Comment: Yes, monkey patching the fit method works with `if callback is None: callback = lambda *x : None`. I just tried it. The fix will be in the next release.